# $(...).niceSelect with Jquery is not a function

Tags: jquery, css, yii2, frontend

I try use nice selector in Yii2.

```
But in console I got error 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceSelect is not a function
    <anonymous> http://frontend/js/anketa.js:49
    jQuery 13
```

I call function in anketa.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').niceSelect();

}
```

My js files in end of layouts

```
<?= $content ?>


    <script src="/js/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery.nice-select.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/anketa.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/js/libs/locomotive.js"></script>-->
    <!--    <script src="js/libs/jquery.smoothscroll.js"></script>-->
    <!-- script src="/js/common.js"></script>-->
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

Comment: That error _always_ means the plugin is not loaded when you come to try to use it. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (at which point you'll probably realise the mistake you've made - and if not someone else will and can answer your question!)

Comment: Do you load that plugin library anywhere?

Comment: Check for multiple loading of jquery *in the rendered HTML output* (ie view source in the browser) - some frameworks load an additional jquery after your one and this "removes" any plugins when you come to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice- 
select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/p09uf73c/2/)